# ReactNative ERROR ,The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload was not handled by any navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am using ReactNative application,
route.ts

```
import React from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Login from './src/screens/Login';
import Dashboard from './src/screens/Dashboard';
import {navigationRef} from './src/RootNavigation';
export const RootStack = createStackNavigator();
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
      <RootStack.Navigator initialRouteName={'Login'}>
        <RootStack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
        <RootStack.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
      </RootStack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
export default Home;
```

RootNavigation.ts

```
 import React from 'react';

export const navigationRef: any = React.createRef();

export function navigate(name: any, params: any) {
  navigationRef.current.navigate(name, params);
}
```

Login.tsx

```
import * as Navigation from '../RootNavigation';
loginAttempt = () => {
    if (
      this.state.username === this.props.userData.username &&
      this.state.password === this.props.userData.password
    ) {
      Navigation.navigate('Dashboard ', {});
    } else {
      Alert.alert('Please try again with correct username and password');
    }
  };
```

Here I am facing issues error while navigating from one screen to another screen;
The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Dashboard ","params":{}} was not handled by any navigator.

Do you have a screen named 'Dashboard '?

If you're trying to navigate to a screen in a nested navigator, see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator.

Comment: As `anthony willis muñoz` points out in his answer, the problem is the extra space in your navigate action. The name must match exactly. So you can just remove that space and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigation Container

```
let navigator;
<NavigationContainer 
           ref={(nav: any) => {
                navigator = nav;
                NavigationService.setNavigator(navigator);
            }}>
      <RootStack.Navigator initialRouteName={'Login'}>
        <RootStack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
        <RootStack.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
      </RootStack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

Navigation Service

```
import { CommonActions, StackActions } from '@react-navigation/native';
const config: any = {};
export function setNavigator(nav: any) {
    if (nav) {
        config.navigator = nav;
    }
}
export function navigate(name: any, params?: any) {
    if (config.navigator && name) {
        const action = CommonActions.navigate({ name, params });
        config.navigator.dispatch(action);
    }
}
export function goBack() {
    if (config.navigator) {
        const action = CommonActions.goBack();
        config.navigator.dispatch(action);
    }
}

export function popToTop() {
    if (config.navigator) {
        const action = StackActions.popToTop();
        config.navigator.dispatch(action);
    }
}
```

Usage

```
import * as NavigationService from 'path';
Navigation.navigate('Dashboard');
```

I think your way should works as well but you have a space here  Navigation.navigate('Dashboard ', {}) instead of Navigation.navigate('Dashboard', {});